# Install VS Code extension during development?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing an extension for VS Code. This extension is already good enough for me to use during daily work, but not good enough to be published (yet). Is there a canonical way to make an unpublished extension under development available to VS Code? Optimally, I would like to always have the current state of the code running.

I did find a way that seems to work, but I'm not sure whether this is a terrible hack or okay: Create a symbolic link in VS Code's extensions directory (`~/.vscode/extensions` on Linux) to the development directory. Is there a better/official way?

Comment: Please study `vsce package` and `code --install-extension` https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_install-from-a-vsix.

Comment: your symlink is usable to have the latest dev version after a restart

Comment: if you want to symlink to a dev build/source, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77376281/11107541

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can package your extension (even if it's in development) using [vsce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vsce) with the command `vsce package`. This will create a .vsix file which you can install in your regular instance of VSCode in the marketplace menu (click on the `...` icon at the top and select "Install from .vsix file).

If you need to view the logs of the extension, go to Help>Toggle Developer tools and use the console to view your extension's output (if there is any).

Comment: It's worth to add that when one is debugging the new extension, while it is also installed, the installed version should be disabled during debugging with the option `--disable-extension ID` in the extension host launch configuration.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code can run the extension directly once it's detected. Just open `extension.js` and run the debugger. See the second step here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension

> Then, inside the editor, press `F5`. This will compile and run the extension in a new Extension Development Host window.

You **do not** need to package it nor run any command line scripts.

Comment: This opens a new window which has the extension installed. It's perfect for isolated testing, but not great for using your not-yet-published extension in real life.

Comment: The question mentions "during development." You do not want to manually package and load the extension every time you make a change. This workflow is continuous and allows for quick reloads. "During testing" however yes, it's best to package it up and use it in your regular profile.